# How can i access Closures preserved variables?

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm trying to get the Closures preserved variables. I'm not sure if that even possible.

Here is my code:

```
function MyBooks (author, title){

      this.author = author;
      this.title = title;

      return function addPrice(amount){

          return amount;
      }

 }
 var MyBooksObj=MyBooks('Tolkin','Hobbit');
 alert(MyBooksObj('100 dollars')); //outpot: 100 dollars
 alert("author: " + MyBooksObj.author); //outpot: author: undefined
 alert("title: " + MyBooksObj.title); //outpot: title: undefined
```

Anybody knows how can i access 'author' and 'title' from outside the function using the variable 'MyBooksObj'?

Thanks!

Comment: This makes no sense. Why are you returning a function from a constructor? Why are you returning anything?

Comment: Unless you use `new MyBooks`, `this.author` and `this.title` makes no sense.

Comment: @JaredSmith This was part of an assignment i got today at  class. See closuers first example https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures. Thank you for letting me know this is bad practice

Comment: @codingnighter2000 when you're using `this` inside a function, generally you don't return anything explicitly. When the function is called with `new` the newly created instance is implicitly returned. The MDN article you linked to shows the correct use of closures (i.e. `var` instead of `this`).

Answer (score 2):

Using the [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator on a function creates a new object with "this" bound to the result.

```js
function MyBooks (author, title){

      this.author = author;
      this.title = title;

      this.addPrice= function (amount){

          return amount;
      }

 }
 var MyBooksObj= new MyBooks('Tolkin','Hobbit');
 alert(MyBooksObj.addPrice('100 dollars')); //output: 100 dollars
 alert("author: " + MyBooksObj.author);     //output: auther: Tolkin
 alert("title: " + MyBooksObj.title);       //output: title: Hobbit
```

Comment: You might want to advise the OP why writing something like this is a horrible idea...

Answer (score 2):

Some error and wrong assumption were made in your code. This is what I feel is going on

- No **new** syntax was used to define your new object.
- When you return a function from an object the object loose hold of it internal structure and only return the function. 
  i.e **MyBooks { author: 'Tolkin', title: 'Hobbit' }**
  becomes
  **[function: addPrice]**
- **amount** variable is not a closure, instead use **this.amount** which store it values in object memory.

so to correct your code. I will suggest this:`

```
        function MyBooks(author, title){
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        this.amount = 0;

        this.addPrice = function(amount){

            return this.amount += amount;
        }

        }
        var MyBooksObj= new MyBooks('Tolkin','Hobbit');
        alert(MyBooksObj); //ouput object
        alert(MyBooksObj.addPrice(100)); //output: 100 dollars
        alert(MyBooksObj.addPrice(100))  //output: 200 dollars
        alert("author: " + MyBooksObj.author); //output: auther: Tolkin
        alert("title: " + MyBooksObj.title); //output: title: Hobbit`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Class and constructor :

```js
class MyBooks {
  constructor(author, title) {
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
  }

  setAmount(value) {
    this.amount = value;
  }

  getAmount() {
    return this.amount;
  }

}

var MyBooksObj= new MyBooks('Tolkin','Hobbit');
MyBooksObj.setAmount('100 dollars');
 alert(MyBooksObj.getAmount()); //outpout: 100 dollars
 alert("author: " + MyBooksObj.author); //outpout: author: Tolkin
 alert("title: " + MyBooksObj.title); //outpout: title: Hobbit
```

More details : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Also interesting : https://coryrylan.com/blog/javascript-es6-class-syntax